# Cordova 5.0.0 getPicture works once, fails on second getPicture

Tags: android, cordova, camera, getpicture

I use the standard documentation implementation to obtain a picture from a gallery and show that on the screen.

The platform is android.

1. I press a button "picture from gallery"
2. A dialog opens from which I choose gallery.
3. The gallery opens and I choose a picture
4. The onSucces function is called and the picture is shown on the screen.

However,

1. I again press the button "picture from gallery" to choose a new picture
2. The onFail function is called with message "Selection Cancelled"
3. A dialog opens from which I choose gallery
4. I choose a picture
5. the dialog of 3. is still shown

Looking for solutions I checked and tried what I found on related topics:

- The Manifest.xml has android:launchMode="singleTop"
- I removed the camera plugin and android platform and re-added them
- I use Cordova 5.0.0
- 
- I test it on a Samsung S4 mini

## Update 1

I found a solution for Android, but I feel it is very ugly, so if anyone has a better solution please suggest:

After processing the 1st succesfull callback, reload the app:

location.reload(); //only for android i guess?